# Remove set of items from list box excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, listboxitem

I am trying to create items and sub-items in a userform listbox. I want to remove the selected sub-item from the list when i click the button. 
Also I want to remove the entire group(item and it's sub-items) when an item is selected and the button is clicked.
The problem is that when an entry from the listbox is removed, the ListBox1.ListCount gets recalculated and the positions saved in the array are no longer valid.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim r As Integer
Dim arr() As Variant
ReDim arr(0)
qq = ListBox1.ListCount
For r = 0 To qq - 1 Step 1
    If ListBox1.Selected(r) = True And Mid(ListBox1.List(r), 1, 1) <> "-" Then
    MsgBox ListBox1.List(r) & " wt"
    arr(UBound(arr)) = r
    ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
        For k = r + 1 To qq - 1 Step 1
        If Mid(ListBox1.List(k), 1, 1) = "-" Then
        MsgBox ListBox1.List(k) & " w"
        arr(UBound(arr)) = k
        ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
        Else
        Exit For
        End If
        Next

    End If
    If ListBox1.Selected(r) = True And Mid(ListBox1.List(r), 1, 1) = "-" Then
    MsgBox ListBox1.List(k) & " w"
    arr(UBound(arr)) = k
    ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
    End If

Next r
MsgBox Join(arr, vbCrLf)
For t = 0 To UBound(arr) - 1
MsgBox arr(t)
ListBox1.RemoveItem arr(t)
Next

End Sub



Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
ListBox1.AddItem "Item 1"
ListBox1.AddItem "-Item 1"
ListBox1.AddItem "-Item 1"
ListBox1.AddItem "-Item 1"
ListBox1.AddItem "Item 2"
ListBox1.AddItem "-Item 2"
ListBox1.AddItem "-Item 2"
ListBox1.AddItem "-Item 2"
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you populating it via an array? What do you mean by sub-items? A screenshot might help.

Comment: I am populating it via UserForm_Initialize(). Array is used to store the positions of the entryes I want to remove. Sub-items are those with "-" before text. (-Item 1, -Item 2).